# PhantomJS - Install and running on PHP server

Tags: phantomjs

I am creating a large PHP web application using Netbeans on a Mac. I am using MAMP Pro as my server, most of the client side etc. is complete.

Now, I would like to have a play with PhantomJS, JQuery to automate a few websites using the headless browser.

So my questions:

- Is it possible to install PhantomJS into my Netbeans project? If so how?
- If I can install to my Netbeans project (on a Mac), can I upload this project to my real server and execute .js files from PHP?

Hope someone can shed some light on this!

Thanks
Carl

Comment: I think you are confusing what MAMP, PhantomJS and Netbeans do. I have not used MAMP, but from the website, it looks like it provides a virtual sandbox for running Apache, MYSQL and other services on your local machine. PhantomJS is a headless browser that you can install on your OS. A Netbeans project is just a container for your code, you can't install anything into it.

Depending on if you have root access to your real server, you might be able to SSH into it and install PhantomJS there. It has nothing to do with Netbeans.

Comment: I am also try... but not success in installation. What is exactly procedure for PhantomJs installation on Mamp